# How to insert all rows in grid at once into SQL Server 2005 database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I need to insert all the rows in a gridview into a SQL Server 2005 database at once.

Number of rows can be 1 to n (not more than 200)

I have investigated the following options:

- Loops: I want to avoid the iterations.
- Table datatype: available in SQL Server 2008 and onwards only
- Bulk Copy: useful in case of bulk data. I am not sure whether I can use it insert less no of rows (performance wise)

What else I can use?

Comment: first try to solve the solution, then think about other alternatives, based on performance. or set up counters to measure the performance.

Comment: If you're stuck on 2005 and cannot update to 2008, and you want to avoid the "iterations" - bulk copy seems to be about the only way to go

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a set-based approach opposed to loops/cursors. Loops and cursors will become less efficient with a larger amount of data, but for relatively small amounts it should be fine.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches

That link should give you a bit of a heads up on how to approach a set-based approach.

Hope this is what you're looking for!